# How to implement max condition using only mathematical functions/expression?

Tags: math, mathematical-expressions

It can be regarding any programming language.

For example in PHP:

```
if($x > 2) { $x=2; }
```

Is there any way to not use a condition, but use some mathematical expression to reach the same result?

Comment: Define "mathematical expression".

Comment: If you are simply looking for a branchless solution, check whether PHP has a `min()` function: `$x = min ($x, 2);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer

```
$maxval = 2;

$x = $maxval - (abs($maxval - $x) + $maxval - $x) / 2;
```

so if $x > $maxval, this expression (abs($maxval - $x) + $maxval - $x) / 2; becomes 0 and $x becomes equal to $maxval
else this expression is equal to $maxval - $x, and the whole equation becomes
$x = $x

but the shortest solution is

```
$x = min($x, 2);
```